# In partial post back ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is not working in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using update panel in `radiobuttonlist`.

On selected index change I am **`rendering a graph`**. First time it is working fine.

But when the Page is get `postback` partially it is not working.

I am using following code to register.

updatePanel Code:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strChartData, false);
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="FusionChartsUP" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="main_div">
            <div class="sec_div">
                <div style="width: 900px;">
                    <!-- Code for Graph-->
                    <asp:Panel ID="panelGraphContent" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                    <div id="dvGraph" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in strChartData = "`<script>Some dummy data </script>`";

> this code is now working perfect on Chrome and IE but not in Firefox. 
>   so is any solution for it.

Comment: Can you please add the Update Panel code also ?

Comment: And plz show strChartData

Answer (score 1):

I always use RegisterStartupScript like that:

```
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="ContentPanel" runat="server">
<!-- YOUR ACTUAL CONTENT-->
</asp:Panel>

</ContentTemplate>
```

and then :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ContentPanel, ContentPanel.GetType(), "updatePanel1Script", "myMagicFunction();", true);
```

Because it registers script for Control INSIDE UpdatePanel.

and in my .js file:

```
function myMagicFunction()
{
//content
};
```

Comment: @user2247651 is your script fired in firefox and it breaks. Or your script isn't even fired?

Comment: have you tried my solution with additional Panel inside and changes in RegisterStartupScript?